# HTML & CSS & Python - How can I have an image stored locally and have it viewed by other clients

Tags: html, css, image, server, local

So, I am using HTML and CSS on my Raspberry Pi 3.

I have an image stored on my raspberry pi `(/home/pi/webapp/templates/SunsetHorizon.jpg)` and if I click on the HTML file it loads up and shows the image but that is local.

I have a server running on the Raspberry Pi, so how can I have an image stored locally on the Raspberry Pi which is running a server and display that image to clients on other devices; such as another computer etc.

The server part is fine it's just displaying an image stored on a device to another device.

This will work, running from my Raspberry Pi. But when I run the server and enter the server's IP Address it doesn't show.

```
file:///home/pi/webapp/templates/Index.html
```

Comment: you need a webserver, such as apache or nginx, and serve it that way via HTTP. Other clients would have to access it as `http://yourPiHostnameOrIPAddress/someoptionalfolderstructure/image.jpg`

Comment: is your server set up to serve html and css?

Comment: Yes I have the server, I am using Python Flask, the server runs fine I can control my Pi's GPIO pins from a web server from my phone, pc, kindle etc. The server works it's just trying to get the image to display from the server's files and display them to clients.

Comment: the image has to be in a location that the webserver can actually serve (i.e. you can address the image file itself via a URL). Have you created an `<img>` tag within your HTML? If so, what does the "src" attribute look like? Does it point to the URL of the image (via http:// not file://)? The path must be relative to the webserver's root folder (or the folder of the virtual site container or whatever), not the filesystem. The client browser cannot see the filesystem, it can only make requests via http.

Comment: `<img src="SunsetHorizon.jpg" alt="Background Image" />`                         That is the line in my HTML code and when I run the server I get the alt text saying "Background Image" so it is being recognised just that the image isn't being displayed.

Comment: Some things to check: is the image in the same folder as your Index.html? Has the webserver got permissions to read it? Is the filename correct (including upper/lower case)? Is the webserver set to serve the relevant MIME type?